# How to create active menus for the content type in drupal 7?

Tags: nodes, routes

I want to create a simple content type with menus ,on clicking each menu the content will be shown on the same block but of the respective menu item.

In this image ,i am having 3 menus a,b ,c with a content .On clicking 'a' menuitem respective content of 'a' will be shown ,on clicking 'b' respective content of 'b' will be shown and so on.

Can anyone help me with this issue![image].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're just about tabs in a content type you could try [this](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_jquery_tabs).